# How to make img src URL as Featured Image

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a "Featured Image" from an `img src` URL with this theme: https://themezee.com/themes/donovan/

```
<a href="https://i.imgur.com/UJs4AKj.jpg"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/UJs4AKj.jpg" /></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please Use below code post Get post featured Image.

```
<?php 
$imageId = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id);
$imageURL = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imageId ), 'full' ); 
echo '<a href="'.$imageURL.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$imageURL.'" /></a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will resolve your problem.

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() ) ): 
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'full' ); ?>
?>
  <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"/>
<?php endif;  ?>
```

Comment: In page post or where you need to display image.

Comment: In which file you are placing the code. File name pls

Comment: i placed at single.php, page.php

Comment: You have to use it within posts loop. It should work